# Intellij IDEA: how hide main menu?

Tags: intellij-idea

After installation of Enterprise Edition I see main menu only when hover a mouse to the up of the screen (with clock on the right). I accidentally pushed some button and now I can't hide main menu.

I am on Lubuntu.

Answer (score 19):

IntelliJ version 2019.2 has now this feature builtin.

To disable the main menu, click on `View > Appearance` then uncheck `Main menu`.

To enable it back press <kbd>ctrl+shift+n</kbd>, then flip the `View | Appearance Main Menu` switch under `Actions tab` menu.

Comment: How to unhide the main menu.

Comment: ctrl+shift+a immediately selects the Actions tab menu. @Tom Perhaps your last sentence could be rewritten with ctrl+shift+a to make it more concise.  Also, "enable it back" could be rephrased to "unhide" to possibly make it clearer.

Answer (score 7):

Have you tried View -> Enter full screen ?
Or is that not what you're looking for?

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>n</kbd> ->
actions tab ->
main menu

Comment: ctrl + shift + a selects the actions tab menu

Answer (score 1):

IntelliJ IDEA Version: 2021.1.3
Build: 211.7628.21

Press shift key two time show popup type view select appearance and check
menu toolbar

shift two time > type view and select >show popup > go appearance > check   menu tool bar

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>n</kbd>[image: The pop-up will open]
From the pop-up click the menu option